# Multiple servlets

Tags: servlets

Is it better to have one servlet running multiple tasks, or have multiple servlets?

eg.
At the moment i have it like this:

ViewCarsServlet
CarViewSalesServlet
AddCarSaleServlet

With each serlvet handliling my requests.

But would it be better to have obne such as CarServlet.
And then pass a Task variable into a If statement?

Which would be better coding practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to have multiple servlets for multiple task. it will not affect performance as well as it is more user friendly, for a particular task we can hit separate servlet instead of making one servlet complex with lot of if else conditions, if we using only one servlet every time we need to check the conditions and then execute the respective task.

Answer (score 0):

Define "better".

My personal taste would group related operations into a single servlet.  I'd think about it as exposing a REST API of operations that went together.  But that's just my personal opinion.  I don't know of a "right" answer that everyone would agree to.

Comment: @Lunar: I think @duffymo is right.You should combine all related operations in one servlet and thats what I do in my work.

Comment: Thanks i will try combine them